# Switch case realization

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I send Get request to the site and depending on a response I have to do smthng.

```
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.site.ru/sfdcsfs/");
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.Method = "GET";
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
req.UserAgent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows 7; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
res1 = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
res1.Close();
switch (res1)
{
    case res1.Headers["XcT"]: log("[+] ok");
    case res1.Headers["Location"].Contains("alreadymember"): log("[-] alreadymember");
    default: log("[-] bad");
}
```

But I have error

```
Error   1   A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type  C:\Users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OdGP\OdGP\Form1.cs  195 29  OdGP
```

Comment: What is it you don'T understand about the error message?

Comment: A switch statement with only one case? Why not just use an `if/else`?

Answer (score 1):

Only some types can be used in switch statement, one of it is string.
 You should not forget about break in switch statement

```
switch (res1.Headers["XcT"].ToString())
{
    case "[+] ok":
       log("[+] ok");
       break;
    default: log("[-] bad");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation on [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statements because there are several errors here.

Your switch expression, `res1`, has a type of `HttpWebResponse` which, as the error says, is not allowed.

The `case` labels must be compile-time constants, arbitrary expressions like `res1.Headers["XcT"]` are also not allowed.

Fall through between labels is not allowed. All case labels (and the `default` label) must have a `break`, a `return`, or throw an exception. The exception to this rule is that you may have multiple labels that execute the same statement block like so:

```
int i = 0;
switch (i) 
{
  case 0:
  case 1:
   Console.WriteLine(i); break;
  default: break;
}
```